# How to send boolean result to ajax call

Tags: ajax

I want to send Boolean result in ajax call.

**Ajax call**

```js
function myMethod() {
   
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
 url : myurl
 dataType : "json",
 contentType: "application/json",
 crossDomain: true,
 success : function(data) {
            alert("success :"+data);
   
 },
 error : function(data) {
        alert("Fialed to get the data");
 }
    });
 
}
```

**Controller method from where I want to send Boolean result.**

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/myMethod", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public boolean myMethod(empId) {
    flag = false;
  
    try {
     if (empId != null)
            newName = Employee.getName(empId);
        else
            newName = Employee.getName();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        flag = true;
        System.out.println("flag :" + flag);
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  
    return flag;
}
```

i want to send the Boolean flag result to ajax call.
How do i send it. dont mind about the logic .. I just want to know how can i send boolean result to ajax call. Please help .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ajax uses HTTP which is a text protocol and has no concept of booleans. However, you can return the strings "1" or "0" to represent your boolean values.

Then, in your "success" callback:

```
success : function ( data ) {
    if ( data * 1 ) {
        // true result
    } else {
        // false result
    }
}
```

Comment: if  if ( data * 1 )  dint get it .. as u suggested I am returning 1 or zero in flag.

Comment: @varun: Because you're returning a string, it needs to be converted to an integer so it can be seen as boolean. Multiplying the result ("0" or "1") by 1 is an easy way in JavaScript to do that.

Comment: so in data I would be having 1 or 0 right .. and to check I just need to do 'if(data===1)'

Comment: If you choose to do that, you should do: if ( data === '1' )

Answer (score 0):

Without passing the Boolean value to the Ajax call, you can do some thing like this using a map. Using this map you can send anything rather than only limiting to Boolean values.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myMethod", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
     public Map<String, Object> myMethod(empId)
     {

     flag=false;

        try {
            if(empId != null)
                newName = Employee.getName(empId);
            else
                newName = Employee.getName();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            flag=true;
            System.out.println("flag :"+flag);
            e1.printStackTrace();


        }
        final Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("flagdata", flag);
        return map;

     }
```

Then you can access this 'flagdata' object in the Ajax call.

Your Ajax code will be some thing like this.

```
$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : myurl
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain:true,
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success :"+data.flagdata);

            },
            error : function(data) {
                alert("Fialed to get the data");
            }
            });
```

Hope it helps.!