# How to prevent ajax from auto quoting boolean and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what happens is that jQuery will turn something like `false` and `1` into `"false"` and `"1"`, which kind of breaks my server code. I can kind of overcome this by using `JSON.stringify` but then I need to `JSON.parse` on the server end. Is there anyway for jQuery to not quote booleans, numbers and anything else that normally doesn't need escaping?

```js
let test = {
  truthy: false
}

let test2 = {
  truthy: false
}

$.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      another: test
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      another: JSON.stringify(test2)
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ajax uses HTTP which is a text protocol and has no concept of booleans. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33910668/5599288

Comment: @JacobGoh ah damn, maybe I should start looking into axios then :\

Comment: but axios is HTTP too ? both jquery ajax and axios are for sending XHR, which stands for XML Http Request. It's HTTP. I think you would have to change how your server code parse the parameters

Comment: @JacobGoh just a bit more worried about polyfilling and stuff like that. I'm pretty sure jquery's ajax works across most browsers.